# jquery animate safari bug

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari

i got a function,

```
            ('#p1').mouseover(function(){
                $('.c01').animate({'opacity':'.90'}, 300, 'linear');
                $('.c01').css('display', 'block');
            });

            $('#p1').mouseout(function(){
                $('.c01').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear');
                $('.c01').css('display', 'none');
            });
```

which is working fine in every browser, except safari - here it gets sloppy and the animation lags.

Does anybody know a solution to solve this bug?

Thank you.

Comment: try to add ` -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` to see if that improves the thing

Comment: why not use [.fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) along with [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) ?

Comment: i tried both, when i add the webkit thing nothing changes. When i replace .animate with .fadeTo the bug disappears, therefore: Thank you.